# editing the footer in joomla1.5

Tags: joomla1.5, footer

I have content in my footer of my joomla 1.5 website. Please help me of how to edit the year and the Powered by joomla content in the footer. How can I edit this?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the footer module in the core Joomla! package by making changes to the following scripts.

```
rootdirectory/modules/mod_footer/tmpl/default.php
rootdirectory/modules/mod_footer/mod_footer.php
```

This is also where you can change things like the date, powered by et cetera.